# Can I change the google account that i created my stack exchange username on?

Tags: support

I would like to log on to my old stack exchange account with a different gmail account. Is this possible?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91466/how-to-migrate-my-id-to-a-new-google-account) looks like it might be what you're looking for.

This is a general SE issue rather than a JLU issue, so you'll probably need to contact an SE admin or post on Stack Overflow meta if the link doesn't help.

Comment: It's alright -- we monitor all meta sites, so there's no need to post elsewhere. :)